# How to update transifex source file?

Tags: translation

I have Transifex Open Translation Platform on my host, and 1 resource in it, when i push my updated source file(POT), languages that used in transifex disappeared. Someone have such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined any teams?

If not and the new source file does not share any strings with the existing one, all existing translations will be deleted and Transifex will not show any statistics for them.